# Como inserir uma variável em uma array?

Tags: banco-de-dados, array, mysqli, variáveis

Desejo inserir dados no meu banco de dados estou usando mysqli, preciso saber como faria para indicar dentro de um array uma variável, aqui e o meu código desejo saber se essa e a forma correta de se fazer isso

```
require 'config.php'
require 'connection.php'

$nomearquivo ="teste.html";
$nome =$_POST["nome"];
$sexo =$_POST["sexo"];
$dia  =$_POST["dia"];
$mes  =$_POST["mes"];
$ano  =$_POST["ano"];
$abre =@fopen("dadosss.html","a+");
$ess  ="nome: " .$nome. " sexo: " .$sexo." ".$dia."/".$mes."/".$ano;
$escreve =fwrite($abre, $ess );

$inserir = array(
    'nome' => $nome, 
    'sexo' => $sexo,
    'dia'  => $dia,
    'mes'  => $mes,
    'ano'  => $ano,

);

$grava = DBCreate('cadastro', $inserir);

if($grava)
    echo 'OK';
```

Comment: **Depois de sanitizar** o `$_POST` você pode passar ele direto para a função. No código da pergunta são criadas  variáveis depois disso elas são reatribuidas em um novo array, não parece muito trabalho isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o `array_push` para resolver o problema.

Comment: obrigado amigo vou tentar